# Is there a known issue with Outlook not being able to handle certain RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, outlook

I am generating an RSS feed that works perfectly fine with Feedly and other RSS readers. However, when trying to import the RSS feed into Microsoft Outlook in particular, I get an error message: "Outlook cannot download the RSS content from [RSS URL] because of a problem connecting to the server."

Interestingly, if I simply save the RSS XML that I'm generating to a static location, then Outlook can import it perfectly fine (but I need to be able to generate the RSS dynamically).

(Seems like someone else has run into this same problem a few years ago, but provided no solution, see: http://tinyurl.com/n3qad49.)

Is this a known issue? Is there any way around it?

Edit: My feeds use HTTPS, which looks to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: Juts out of curiosity, can Redemption add that RSS link to Outlook (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdorssfeeds.htm)?

Comment: I had the same error message here.
This solution worked for me: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2549423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the problem is HTTPS...other users have had issues where Outlook can't do HTTPS.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/69de39ff-7924-45d7-a48e-2c0e02beec7d/outlook-rss-ovel-ssl-problem

http://themetaq.com/articles/how-to-fix-the-secure-rss-glitch-in-outlook